# Blocking stupid videos on YouTube

Tags: youtube, spam-prevention, firefox-extensions, greasemonkey

There are a lot of really stupid/trolly/fake videos on YouTube.  I'd like to blacklist them forever when I see them, so I don't accidentally click on them in the future, and sometimes block the uploader, too, to avoid others in the same vein.  Is there any way to do this?  Greasemonkey script?  Adblock?  Firefox extension?  Proxy site for Youtube?

Something like [BlockSite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/blocksite/) would be good, in that it disables hyperlinks to specific URLs, but ideally, it would hide everything related to those videos, thumbnails, etc., not just disable the links.  Also, last time I tried it, BlockSite was buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that YouTube has this built-in now!  Next to a video there are three dots, if you click them, you get this menu:

[image: Screenshot of YouTube video menu: Add to queue Save to Watch later Save to playlist Not interested Don't recommend channel Report]

If you click "Not interested" it shows this:

[image: Screenshot of YouTube video message: Video removed UNDO TELL US WHY]

and then if you click "tell us why" you can block recommendations based on a video you watched:

[image: Screenshot of YouTube video menu: Tell us why I've already watched the video I don't like the video I'm not interested in recommendations based on:]

If you click "Don't recommend channel" it shows this:

[image: Screenshot of YouTube video message: We won't recommend videos from this channel to you again MORE INFO UNDO]

Comment: and since Video Blocker add-no no longer works, and this is available to everyone, I will change this to the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to block a video within YouTube. You can block a user though by navigating to the users profile and clicking block user.

If you are looking specifically for a browser extension then please flag this question for migration to SuperUser. (Browser extensions are off-topic here as per the [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq))

Comment: Blocking a user does not seem to hide their videos

Answer (score 2):

if you're a firefox user, there's an add-on called [youtube ratings preview](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-bogus-remover/?src=search). it shows the percentage of ratings on both search results and recommended videos on video page, but not on 'load more suggestions' results.

not the ideal i guess, but it helps.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, but I upvoted it because it at least helps with it.

Answer (score 2):

- Add this **[Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-blocker/jknkjnpcbbgcbdbaampbjlhkcghmgfhk/related?hl=en)** / **[Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/video-blocker/)** extension to your browser:
- Find stupid video
- Right-click on the video title
- Select **Block videos from this channel**

[image: 0]

- Right after you can see that video disappeared from the list:

[image: 0]

- Upon clicking the icon you can enter options or quickly add new blocking rules

[image]

- You can block whole channels, all videos of the channel or sets of videos... also you can block keywords, comments or video titles... regex expressions are also supported as well as password protection or exporting/importing rules even synchronization

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might help: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/156278.html

This script removes youtube users you choose from appearing in:

- Recommended Channels tab
- Recommended/related videos
- Search results
- My subscriptions/What to watch (if someone you are subscribed to likes/favorites a video from them)